# Invalid predicate when filtering CKRecords by the same keys

Tags: swift, nspredicate, ckrecord

I have a CKRecord type "Follow" which stores the user's ID and the ID of a friend they follow. (Assume that a user can only follow 1 person and the logic around that is handled elsewhere). Screenshot of record definition in CloudKid: http://screencast.com/t/Tb83lyjLV7

I want to query the Follow records to confirm that two users follow each other and are in fact, friends.

These are the base queries. Each works fine on it's own

```
let followPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "userID == %@ AND followsID == %@", userId, followsID)
let followedPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "followsID == %@ AND userID == %@", userId, followsID)
```

I want to combine these two predicates and query once, so that if two records come back, it's assumed that the different users follow each other

I've tried to combine them both manually and by using a NSCompoundPredicate:

```
let friendPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [followPredicate, followedPredicate])
let friendPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(followsID == %@ AND userID == %@) OR (userID == %@ AND followsID == %@)", userId, followsID, userId, followsID)
```

I then use the query here:

```
let friendQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "Follow", predicate: friendPredicate)
```

In both versions of friendPredicate above, I get an Invalid Predicate Exception.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Invalid predicate: (userID == "_1570bb2652d0658c12320bcd658e5898" AND followsID ==
"_fb7ebeb0841f6411099ad094424d66ac") OR (followsID == 
"_1570bb2652d0658c12320bcd658e5898" AND userID == 
"_fb7ebeb0841f6411099ad094424d66ac") 
(Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=12 "Invalid predicate (userID == 
"_1570bb2652d0658c12320bcd658e5898" AND followsID == 
"_fb7ebeb0841f6411099ad094424d66ac") OR (followsID == 
"_1570bb2652d0658c12320bcd658e5898" AND userID == 
"_fb7ebeb0841f6411099ad094424d66ac")" 
UserInfo=0x14e63010 {ck_isComparisonError=false, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid predicate (userID == 
"_1570bb2652d0658c12320bcd658e5898" AND followsID == 
"_fb7ebeb0841f6411099ad094424d66ac") OR (followsID == 
"_1570bb2652d0658c12320bcd658e5898" AND userID == 
"_fb7ebeb0841f6411099ad094424d66ac")})'
```

Am I approaching this wrong or making an invalid assumption?
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I've just run into very similar. "is not a comparison predicate", when trying to use a Bool value comparison in the same predicate as a recordID comparison.

Comment: Actually, it looks as though it's as simple as "OR" queries being unsupported by CloudKit. That's quite a limitation!

Comment: I didn't unfortunately. I wish I could tell you this we just an abandoned post :) did you find anything to support that or just process of elimination?

Comment: It looks to me as though they simply don't support OR queries at all. I searched through the CKQuery doc page and OR isn't mentioned once, nor is it listed as one of the supported operands.

Comment: Dang. Well, thanks for the info